# Jquery search table can't find word with parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this jquery code that search the table with words.

but i can't seem to find words with parenthesis.

```
$(function () {
$(' #search ').click(function () {

    var str = $('#emp_search').val();
    var strary = str.split(' ');

    $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());

        for (var i = 0; i < strary.length; i++) {
            console.log("%s:%s", text, strary[i]);
            var regex = new RegExp(".*\\b" + strary[i] + "\\b\.*", "gi");
            $(this).toggle(regex.test(text));
            console.log(regex.test(text));
            if (regex.test(text)) break;
         }
       });
    });
});
```

here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wind_chime18/ANLgD/22/

Comment: If you mean that you want to search for the parentheses they need to be escaped in a regex, also your regex already includes `\b` which will match the parentheses anyway, so you have a bit of a conflict there...

Comment: @nnnnnn  how sir. please show me some codes. I don't know how cause this code is only i got in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this jquery plugins standard and easy !

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Or

http://datatables.net/

Comment: that's to complicated. and it has license.

Comment: Check this steps : http://heathesh.com/post/2010/05/06/Filtering-or-searching-an-HTML-table-using-JavaScript.aspx